# Add a second input box to further separate displayed data?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that has a hidden sheet with a large data set (sheet2). In Sheet 1 I have job codes in column A and their corresponding job title in column B. The user presses a button and types in a job code from column A. The script then looks in the hidden sheet and spits out one select data from two other columns (besides code and title) and places it in a nice readable format.

Code:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim lJobCode As String
    Dim lLob As String
    Dim sFirst As String
    Dim sResults As String
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Long

    lJobCode = Application.InputBox("Please provide a job code", "Job Code", Type:=2)
    lLob = Application.InputBox("Please provide a line of business", "BU_Level_02", Type:=2)

    If lJobCode = "False" Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel


    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    rw = 3

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("A")
        Set rFound = .Find(lJobCode, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            sFirst = rFound.Address
            Do
            If Cells(rFound.Row, 5).Value = lLob Then
                sh1.Cells(rw, 4) = rFound.Offset(, 0).Value
                sh1.Cells(rw, 5) = rFound.Offset(, 1).Value
                sh1.Cells(rw, 6) = rFound.Offset(, 2).Value
                sh1.Cells(rw, 7) = rFound.Offset(, 3).Value
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
                rw = rw + 1
            End If
            Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst

        Else
            MsgBox "Job Code [" & lJobCode & "] not found.", , "Error"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Sheet 2 has the raw data, Sheet 1 has just the job code and job title. The appended `lLob` variable is available in a drop down list in cell A6 of sheet 1 and will be chosen before macro is run. Why is my `If Cells(rFound.Row, 5).Value = lLob Then` statement not recognizing my fifth column in my Sheet2?

table in hidden sheet:

column A (job codes)

Column B (Job titles)

Column c (business unit lvl 4)

Column d (business unit lvl 5)

Column e (line of business 1 2 or 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this. The first and possibly easiest would be to add another input box and ask the user to enter in the code that you want to filter by. This would require them to enter in the exact string that you want to filter by and might not necessarily be super user friendly as the user might not exactly enter in "1".

My suggestion would be create a UserForm object and create the custom controls that you need to get the exact user requirements for the data call. Most of your code could migrate fairly easily into the UserForm module or you could call this code from the UserForm and provide the inputs as parameters.

Either way is pretty easy unless you haven't used UserForms before. If you haven't, [here](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html) is a good example.

Comment: I figured out an if statement for it, but it's not working--it just skips over without pulling the row data I need. Any idea how to get the if statement to recognize the 1's I put in column E of sheet 2? A userform is just too complex for me at this point, so input boxes suffice.

Comment: Not sure what if statement you are talking about, but finding all of the "1"'s in  a certain column should be pretty easy.

    Dim cel as Range
    
    for each cel in sht2.Range("E1:E" & sht2.Cells(sht.Rows.Count,"E").End(xlUp).Row

        if cel.Value = 1 Then _
            MsgBox cel.Address

    Next cel